# TFS Build Agent failed on Nuget Restore for: .Net Core + VS 2017 + private TFS Feed

Tags: .net-core, tfsbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have: a .NET Core App, modified for VS 2017 and consuming a TFS Feed.
When it was in **VS 2015**, `NuGet restore` was working fine.
Now using **VS 2017**, `NuGet restore` it doesn't work returning a `Failed to load msbuild Toolset` ... `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=14.0.0.0`

I also try to use `dotnet restore` and I got a `401 (Unauthorized)` response.

Apparently `NuGet restore` is the preferred way to do it, since it automatically authenticated for us, in order to use TFS Feed, but it seems to don't recognize VS 2017.

### Update 3/20/2017

Sorry for the confusion, I forgot to mention that the problem is using CI/CD Visual Studio Team Services / Build. In my PC, it works fine because I had NuGet 4 (it come with VS 2017)... but online the NuGet versions available (with access to private feed) are: 3.3 and 3.5

### Update 3/25/2017

After I added the nuget 4.0 to the build as @Cece-MSFT suggested, I still getting an error but without much detail. see screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Which version of Nuget are you using?

Comment: Do you use Hosted Agent? Try to add Nuget.config (can be your local nugget.config) to version control and map to build agent, then specify the nugget.config file (Path to Nuget.config of Nuget install step/task). On the other hand, try to set system.debug to true (variables tab) and check whether there is detail error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, some upgrades and there are 2 options, how to solve this:

1. Instead of using NuGet v3.3 and v3.5... there is now support for NuGet v4.0

[image]

2. And my Favorite, It's to use a NuGet Restore version v1.*, and now I have the option to **select my own VSTS Feed**... so I don't need the NuGet.config file anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the nuget global config file of your build server located in %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with TFS 2017 + VS 2017 + Nuget 4.0.0.2323, after add the TFS feed in Package Source in VS, VS can restore it successfully.

You may compare your environment with mine, especially Nuget version, as someone has similar issue with a previous Nuget version, check: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3975

=========================================================================

**Add a screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Very strange, I got: Spawn ENOENT Error

Comment: @Jaider What do you mean Spawn ENOENT error? Provide the detail error message here.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Is there a way to download version 4.0 via TFS?  I would like to not have to put it in source control.  Also seems strange that it is not available even though VS 2017 uses it.  I tried adding it as a demand but haven't found the location of nuget.exe 4.0

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Also, I have the same error reported by @@Jaider. It detects the correct version then:```Error: utilities/nuget.exe failed. spawn utilities/nuget.exe ENOENT```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several of the suggestions from @Cece-MSFT but was unable to get those to work without errors.  Here is what did work for me.  I had to check in the 4.0.* version of nuget.exe into version control. I added a command line utility and executed my checked in nuget.exe and everything worked perfectly.

Note: This also works with a mix of .net core and asp.net framework class libraries.  This was an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3199) reported on github.

Note2: I am using the .csproj version (VS 2017, no project.json) for all my .net core projects in my solution.

Here is a screen of my nuget restore build step. Hope this helps someone.

[image]

Comment: The problem I am facing is that I am trying to reach my private repository (**TFS Feed Package**), and this answer will need to add `Nuget.config` + `permissions` and it is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing the nuget restore step and adding /t:restore on the msbuild arguments. By doing that you don't need to manually upgrade nuget.

Comment: I tried that but again, msbuild is not authorize to consume private TFS Feed.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this by making sure the following settings are used on the build:

- Agent is hosted but **NOT** Hosted VS2017
- Nuget restore task is v3.5
- Build task specifies VS2017

No idea why you need this specific combination haha!

Just realised that you are building a CORE app sorry. For this the restore is fine by then the build fails expanding the packages. One step closer I suppose!

Answer (score 0):

I had a different cause, in VSTS/Azure DevOps using "Use Nuget" first then "NuGet restore" second, on Hosted agent...the restore was throwing this error.

I had to change this...

```
Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json: **/*.sln
```

to this...

```
Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json: **\{YOUR_SOLUTION_NAME}.sln
```

And the error went away.

Hope this helps!